# How to plot the Euler's formula in 3D?

Tags: plotting, stability

In [Von Neumann's stability analysis of Finite Difference Equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis), the [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) is used to describe a perturbation. Now the finite difference equation is stable if this perturbation does not grow in time.

Now, my question really is: how do I plot the perturbation (Equation 1) three-dimensions(?)/Im vs Real dimensions?

$$\epsilon(x,t) = \sum_{m=1}^{M} e^{at} e^{ik_m x} \ldots \ldots \text{(1)}$$

I realize that the the Euler's formula $e^{ik_m x}$ [describes a circle](http://www.songho.ca/math/euler/euler.html). Clearly the multiplicative amplitude factor $e^{at}$ either "grows" this circle or decreases it whether or not $e^{at}$ is greater than 1 or not.

I would like to describe that as a `Manipulate` or a `ListAnimate` in *Mathematica* but I don't understand which function to use.

So far I have understood that `PolarPlot` and `ParametricPlot` draw this circle in 2D.

**Parametric Plot example**

```
ParametricPlot[G {Re[Exp[I x]], Im[Exp[I x]]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

**Polar Plot example**

```
PolarPlot[{Re[Exp[I x]], Im[Exp[I x]]}, {x, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question asks, in part, "Clearly the multiplicative amplitude factor $e^{at}$ either "grows" this circle or decreases it whether or not $e^{at}$ is greater than 1 or not. I would like to describe that as a Manipulate or a ListAnimate in Mathematica." Here's one way to visualize the growing and/or shrinking.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[a {Re[Exp[I x]], Im[Exp[I x]]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {a, 0.1, 2}]
```

This draws the circle and let's you change the radius by moving the slider to specify different `a` values.

[image]